# How to add a new icon from Font Awesome to an older version?

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I have Font Awesome 4 on website.

I tried to add TikTok logo as following but it doesn't show up on website as tiktok logo support started in Font Awesome version 5.13.1:

`<i class="fa fa-tiktok"></i>`

**Question**:

How can I add one logo from newer Font Awesome versions while keeping old version 4? Thus avoiding to modify syntax from `fa` to `fas` across all the website?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714120/19042967

Comment: @GaneshThorat thanks but this is to have 2 Font Awesome versions side by side which I can't do because I need to avoid additional requests and libraries.